# How do I make EditText show my text input?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I created a login screen with textinput, but I noticed that whenever I entered a character into the editText, it wouldn't show the letters I typed in. I'd greatly appreciate if you helped me with this.

My EditText code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.23"
        android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.709"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.427" />
```

Comment: Try changing the background of your app or the text color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the color and size of your text.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my text color to black and everything worked out:).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `EditText` properties `android:textColor` to black or try remove backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

you can give `android:textColor=""` which clearly see on background color 
which you has given in 
`android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"`

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my text color to black and everything worked out:).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set this attribute:

```
android:alpha="0.23"
```

this will make the text unreadable.
Remove it and if the problem persists try a different `textColor`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed my text color to black and everything worked out:).